# How to receive json request data in Struts 2 Action class, that's sent by getJSON() of jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2

I am creating a Struts 2 based web application in which I want to send a request containing JSON data by `getJSON()` of jQuery to an Action class. This much is happening.

However my Action class is unable to receive JSON data. Any effort is much appreciated in advance.

```
$.getJSON("getPaycells", {
    level: $(this).val(), 
    ajax: 'true'
}, function(j){});
```

`<action>` element in struts.xml:

```xml
<action name="getPaycells" class="pkg.ActionClassName">    
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="ERROR" />
    <interceptor-ref name="json">
        <param name="contentType">application/json</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result type="json"/>
</action>
```

Action class:

```
public class PayMatrix extends ActionSupport
{
    private Map data = new HashMap();

    public Map getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.print("MYDATA-"+data);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not JSON data. To get started with Ajax read https://struts.apache.org/docs/ajax.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good article at http://tech.learnerandtutor.com/send-json-object-to-struts-2-action-by-jquery-ajax/

Try to set `enableSMD` to true

```
<interceptor-ref name="json">
  <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

Also try to use some thing like below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "writeJSON.action",
    data: data1,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    success: function (res) {
        ....
    }
});
```

The `json interceptor` discard your request if it dose not have specific properties.

I myself solved my issue by setting some break points at `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor`  the `intercept` method, this will help me why the interceptor not apply on my request.